# Getting bar chart with negative values to display in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-10.4, graph

Using ArcMap 10.4 I'm trying to display bar charts to represent the changes that occurred at several locations. At one point, the change was always negative, and so are the three values (-3; -1; -4). For whatever reason, the chart at this point won't display.

I think it has to do with the values all being negative. There is no issue when negative values are displayed with a positive value.

Any suggestions on how to get a bar chart with negative values to display?

Comment: Would you be able to [edit] your question to revise it with a more precise list of the steps that you performed prior to getting stuck, please?